# Volume / gain too high with ALSA under Debian for an USB sound card

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian, alsa

I encounter some issues configuring audio with ALSA on my Seagate Dockstar on which I plugged a little USB audio card.

I'm able to play music with MOC but I'm stuck with a volume way to high.

Whatever I tried, the gain of the PCM control is stuck above +10dB even when the sliders of alsamixer are at 0%, and the sound is really too loud unless muted (speakers or headphones).

When I increase the volume, the gain grows further and the resulting volume increases further too, so the control of the volume works, but the problem is that it begins at +10dB instead of -48dB.

This is the output of `amixer` command when I lower the volume at the minimum without muting:

```
root@host:~# amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 13568
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 1 [0%] [10.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [10.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 6096
  Mono: Capture 0 [0%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Notice the [10.00dB] even if I'm at 0% volume.

I followed this [**guide**](http://wiki.daviddarts.com/Debian_on_the_Seagate_Dockstar_Post-Installation#USB_Audio) to configure it all.

I remember that I followed this before (more than one year ago), and that it worked back then, but I can't remember if I had to tweak something specific or not at that time.

I don't want to install Pulseaudio if possible, as I really think it is overkill for just the sake of playing a sound file (for those who don't know what the Dockstar is, it is a dock for hard drives which features 4 USB connectors + 1 Ethernet Gigabit, with a "motherboard" based on an Kirkwood ARM architecture).

I just did a base-install of Debian Squeeze and this is console only. I really want to avoid to install all the x11 dependencies of Pulseaudio.

Moreover I know that it worked in the past without the need to install more than ALSA.

**TLDR: How can I alter the base gain of the PCM channel in ALSA?**

Here is the [**Output**](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=45f77f95ca8d10afb7330966c1d9f00b283357a3) of an information script which shows all my current config.

NB: I already tried to use `max_dB` and `min_dB` in `/etc/asound.conf` as proposed [**here**](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1090109#p1090109), without success.

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: No, would still welcome an idea on how to solve this.